# ConditionalOnClass, why JVM allow the class not in classpath in runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jvm

After study and using spring boot, I understand the usage and the logic behind the spring boot ConditionalOnClass, my questions are:

1. why "Since this annotation is parsed by loading class bytecode, it is safe to specify classes here that may ultimately not be on the classpath".
2. Where is the JVM spec related this?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.java#L39

```
/**
 * The classes that must be present. Since this annotation is parsed by loading class
 * bytecode, it is safe to specify classes here that may ultimately not be on the
 * classpath, only if this annotation is directly on the affected component and
 * <b>not</b> if this annotation is used as a composed, meta-annotation. In order to
 * use this annotation as a meta-annotation, only use the {@link #name} attribute.
 * @return the classes that must be present
 */
Class<?>[] value() default {};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Spring catches ClassNotFoundException.
Check source code - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d3c34ee3d1bfd3db4a98678c524e145ef9bca51c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/OnClassCondition.java#L218